# I have a collection with values for the elements of each collection, and I want to distribute the elements as evenly as possible on N pieces by value

Tags: algorithm, scala

I have a collection with values for the elements of each collection, and I want to distribute the elements as evenly as possible on N pieces by value.

I tried to use scala code to complete the following result, but never got a good way and it's easy to die looping

Like this :

```
Map("table1"->100,"table2"->500,"table3"->20000,"table4"->10,"table5"->1000,"table6"->200,"table7"->10000)
```

for 4 pieces，I want to get as average results as possible.

```
Map("table7"->10000)
Map("table3"->20000)
Map("table1"->100,"table2"->500,"table4"->10,"table4"->10,"table5"->1000,"table6"->200)
Map()
```

or ，It's perfect

```
Map("table7"->10000)
Map("table3"->20000)
Map("table1"->100,"table2"->500,"table4"->10,"table4"->10,"table6"->200)
Map("table5"->1000)
```

---

I used @ [Krzysztof Atłasik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1303324/krzysztof-at%C5%82asik) 's code,and got result has duplicated.10 buckets.
formula data is:

```
val testMap=Map("test_7d_all_qr "->1,"test_daily_advertise_position "->1,"test_7d_province "->94,"test_city_statistics "->34916,"test_30days_page_view "->11,"test_30days_ad_anomaly_auth_analyze "->26,"tt_user_grouping "->1,"oauth_refresh_tokens "->42,"tt_daily_share "->4476,"test_ad_anomaly_ip_analyze "->148,"test_7d_ad_anomaly_time_analyze "->15,"share_tool_template "->1,"test_30days_visit_duration "->70,"tt_qr_group_01 "->1,"tt_seven_user_tmp "->35890,"test_qr_code_statistics_temporary "->1,"tt_cms_scene "->1,"test_30days_terminal_analysis "->1406,"test_7d_terminal_analysis "->765,"test_7d_single_scene "->51,"test_30days_single_scene "->77,"test_monitor_daily_new_user "->1,"tt_ad_authorize "->1,"tt_sdk_version_appcount "->1,"test_ad_anomaly_auth_analyze "->428,"tt_attribute_relationship "->1,"test_7d_page_view "->9,"tt_ad_user_info "->1,"phone_model "->1,"share_tool_var "->1,"share_tool_type_template "->1,"tt_stay_logs_link "->8,"test_advertise_home_hour "->4,"test_monitor_hourly "->1,"test_7d_phonebrand "->71,"tt_cms_system "->1,"test_7d_city_statistics "->297,"test_link_cheat_protect "->1,"test_daily_advertise_link "->1,"test_30days_trend_analysis "->17,"tt_cms_log "->1,"test_hourly_advertise_position "->6,"push_join_info "->1,"test_monitor_daily_app "->5,"test_7d_event "->491,"cms_boss_words "->1,"test_daily_error "->13903,"test_user_activity "->569,"tt_event "->127,"test_link_summary_hour "->290,"test_7d_single_qr_group "->1,"tt_sdk_log "->1,"tt_code "->42,"test_page_view "->11689,"tt_7d_device_statistics "->709,"test_7d_ad_anomaly_ip_analyze "->15,"cms_wx_data "->1,"tt_sdk_version_apps "->311,"test_qr_code_statistics "->138,"test_daily_link "->709,"test_30days_event "->974,"test_7d_error "->1,"test_30days_city_statistics "->527,"tt_link_trace "->8,"test_7d_single_position "->1,"test_30days_single_link "->5,"test_daily_event "->33480,"tt_share_page "->53,"tt_30days_hierarchy_share "->1,"tt_stay_logs "->17149,"test_dailyshare_gender "->282,"test_hourly_advertise_media "->6,"test_monitor_daily_link "->4,"tt_device_statistics "->66629,"oauth_authorization_codes "->73,"test_ad_anomaly_all_analyze "->5488,"test_30days_userShare_top10 "->943,"test_daily_funnel "->782,"oauth_scopes "->1,"top100070922 "->0,"test_7d_userShare_top10 "->639,"tt_hierarchy_share "->148,"oauth_clients "->1,"user_phone "->0,"tt_sms_queue "->2,"tt_cms_article "->1,"test_monitor_daily "->1,"cms_source_type "->1,"test_30days_entrance_page "->11,"test_30days_ad_anomaly_all_analyze "->636,"oauth_jwt "->1,"tt_cms_user "->1,"tt_ci_sessions "->38,"test_7d_link_monitor "->1,"test_daily_link_monitor "->2717,"test_hourly_qr_group "->239,"tt_7d_hierarchy_share "->1,"test_30days_event_paras "->1,"tt_event_link_funnel "->2,"test_blackIP_setting "->1,"test_visit_duration "->2476,"tt_qr_group "->19,"test_hourly_scene "->41057,"test_30days_ad_anomaly_time_analyze "->26,"test_hourly_scene_group "->24908,"tt_smartLink_dict_name "->1,"test_scene_statistics "->7868,"test_30days_single_entrance_page "->59,"test_online_status "->1,"convert_path "->1,"user_group_funnel_daily "->7,"test_daily_media "->238,"test_grey_ak "->1,"cms_market "->1,"test_dailyshare_top10 "->10329,"test_hourly_qr "->334,"test_monitor_daily_trend "->8,"test_dailyshare_source "->224,"test_ad_anomaly_time_analyze "->158,"test_30days_scene_group "->34,"test_hourly_share_summary "->2895,"test_30days_single_page_view "->107,"service_user_view "->1,"tt_funnel "->1,"test_30days_single_qr_group "->1,"test_monitor_hourly_link "->12,"test_30days_error "->1,"test_daily_scene_group "->3702,"test_smartLink_day_analysis "->5770,"tt_prevent_cheat "->1,"test_hourly_advertise_link "->8,"tt_wechat_user_bind "->440049,"user_apps "->110,"test_dailyshare_page "->1394,"test_link_summary "->57,"test_smartLink_summary_analysis "->352,"share_tool_code "->1,"test_7d_trend_analysis "->15,"test_7d_event_paras "->1,"tt_sdk_history "->1,"tt_mini_code_authorize "->1,"test_visit_depth "->1852,"test_daily_entrance_page "->1254,"tt_private_construct_info "->1,"test_monitor_hourly_trend "->14,"tt_user_etl "->12914,"test_7d_scene_group "->26,"test_30days_link_summary "->1,"test_7d_visit_depth "->43,"tt_task "->1,"tt_code_share "->29,"tt_authorization "->1,"test_daily_advertise_media "->1,"share_tool_user_template "->1,"tt_30days_device_statistics "->1301,"tt_code_tool "->21,"test_30days_single_media "->2,"tt_scene_link "->1,"tt_code_sem "->2,"tt_stay_logs_media "->4,"tt_mini_radio "->1,"tt_sdk_notice "->1,"test_entrance_page "->5209,"test_terminal_analysis "->91350,"test_7d_single_entrance_page "->39,"test_7d_visit_duration "->57,"cms_analy_bind "->1,"test_30days_link_monitor "->1,"test_hourly_trend_analysis_debug "->1,"test_advertise_home "->1,"tt_stay_logs_position "->4,"test_30days_single_position "->1,"tt_smartLink_dict "->114,"test_ad_anomaly_all_analyze_hour "->1,"test_monitor_hourly_qr "->1,"test_smartLink_hour_analysis "->39287,"test_hourly_position "->843,"tt_cms_scene_type "->1,"test_dailyshare_city "->2915,"test_operation_log "->1,"oauth_access_tokens "->42,"share_tool_type "->1,"test_hourly_media "->1432,"tt_mini_routine_push "->6,"test_daily_position "->92,"test_app_summary "->1,"test_trend_analysis_debug "->1,"test_daily_phonebrand "->6565,"test_daily_share_summary "->371,"test_third_setup "->1,"user_app_relations "->20,"test_7d_single_link "->2,"tt_field_mapping "->1,"test_event_paras "->684271,"test_7d_entrance_page "->9,"test_dailyshare_user "->548969,"test_region_statistics "->11658,"test_7d_ad_anomaly_all_analyze "->396,"test_30days_visit_depth "->53,"tt_authorize "->6,"test_30days_province "->148,"tt_ad_activity_hourly "->714,"test_7d_link_summary "->1,"oauth_users "->1,"test_monitor_daily_qr "->1,"test_30days_phonebrand "->117,"test_7d_single_media "->1,"tt_db_split "->1,"test_30days_ad_anomaly_ip_analyze "->25,"service_user "->1,"test_monitor_hourly_share "->34,"test_hourly_trend_analysis "->16825,"test_30days_all_qr "->1,"test_trend_analysis "->2196,"aladdin_user "->4,"test_30days_single_qr "->3,"test_daily_page_view "->1295,"tt_stay_logs_bak "->250,"test_hourly_link "->3199,"tt_media "->3,"test_7d_ad_anomaly_auth_analyze "->15,"test_7d_single_qr "->1,"test_daily_qr_group "->37,"test_7d_single_page_view "->70,"user_feedback "->1,"test_user_activity_details "->2486,"test_monitor_daily_share "->1)
```

I got this result

```
Map(test_event_paras  -> 684271)
Map(test_dailyshare_user  -> 548969)
Map(tt_wechat_user_bind  -> 440049)
Map(test_terminal_analysis  -> 91350)
Map(test_daily_qr_group  -> 37, tt_stay_logs_bak  -> 250, test_hourly_link  -> 3199, test_7d_single_page_view  -> 70, tt_device_statistics  -> 66629, test_monitor_hourly_trend  -> 14, test_smartLink_summary_analysis  -> 352, test_7d_single_scene  -> 51, test_user_activity  -> 569, tt_hierarchy_share  -> 148, test_daily_page_view  -> 1295, tt_smartLink_dict  -> 114, test_trend_analysis  -> 2196, test_30days_trend_analysis  -> 17, test_7d_terminal_analysis  -> 765)
Map(aladdin_user  -> 4, test_30days_ad_anomaly_ip_analyze  -> 25, tt_stay_logs_bak  -> 250, test_30days_scene_group  -> 34, test_hourly_link  -> 3199, test_7d_single_page_view  -> 70, tt_device_statistics  -> 66629, test_smartLink_summary_analysis  -> 352, test_7d_single_scene  -> 51, test_user_activity  -> 569, tt_hierarchy_share  -> 148, test_daily_page_view  -> 1295, tt_smartLink_dict  -> 114, test_advertise_home_hour  -> 4, test_trend_analysis  -> 2196, test_7d_terminal_analysis  -> 765)
Map(aladdin_user  -> 4, test_30days_ad_anomaly_ip_analyze  -> 25, tt_stay_logs_bak  -> 250, test_30days_scene_group  -> 34, test_hourly_link  -> 3199, test_7d_single_page_view  -> 70, tt_device_statistics  -> 66629, test_smartLink_summary_analysis  -> 352, test_7d_single_scene  -> 51, test_user_activity  -> 569, tt_hierarchy_share  -> 148, test_daily_page_view  -> 1295, tt_smartLink_dict  -> 114, test_trend_analysis  -> 2196, test_7d_terminal_analysis  -> 765, tt_media  -> 3)
Map(aladdin_user  -> 4, test_30days_ad_anomaly_ip_analyze  -> 25, tt_stay_logs_bak  -> 250, test_30days_scene_group  -> 34, test_hourly_link  -> 3199, test_7d_single_page_view  -> 70, tt_device_statistics  -> 66629, test_smartLink_summary_analysis  -> 352, test_7d_single_scene  -> 51, test_user_activity  -> 569, tt_hierarchy_share  -> 148, test_daily_page_view  -> 1295, tt_smartLink_dict  -> 114, test_trend_analysis  -> 2196, test_7d_terminal_analysis  -> 765, tt_event_link_funnel  -> 2)
Map(aladdin_user  -> 4, test_30days_ad_anomaly_ip_analyze  -> 25, tt_stay_logs_bak  -> 250, test_30days_scene_group  -> 34, test_hourly_link  -> 3199, test_7d_single_page_view  -> 70, tt_device_statistics  -> 66629, test_smartLink_summary_analysis  -> 352, test_7d_single_scene  -> 51, test_user_activity  -> 569, tt_hierarchy_share  -> 148, test_daily_page_view  -> 1295, tt_smartLink_dict  -> 114, test_trend_analysis  -> 2196, test_7d_terminal_analysis  -> 765, tt_sdk_history  -> 1)
Map(aladdin_user  -> 4, test_30days_ad_anomaly_ip_analyze  -> 25, tt_stay_logs_bak  -> 250, test_30days_scene_group  -> 34, test_hourly_link  -> 3199, test_7d_single_page_view  -> 70, tt_device_statistics  -> 66629, user_phone  -> 0, test_smartLink_summary_analysis  -> 352, test_7d_single_scene  -> 51, test_user_activity  -> 569, tt_hierarchy_share  -> 148, test_daily_page_view  -> 1295, top100070922  -> 0, tt_smartLink_dict  -> 114, test_trend_analysis  -> 2196, test_7d_terminal_analysis  -> 765)
```

---

I rewritten a method in the way of [Krzysztof Atłasik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1303324/krzysztof-at%C5%82asik) , and the result is correct.

```
def distributeMy(elements: Map[String, Long], bucketCount: Long) = {
    implicit val ordering: Ordering[(Long, Map[String, Long])] = Ordering.by(-_._1)
    val map = elements.toList.sortBy(-_._2)
    var bucket =new mutable.TreeSet[(Long,Map[String,Long])]

    map.foreach{
      case (k:String,v:Long) =>{
        if(bucket.size < bucketCount){
          bucket.add((v,Map(k->v)))
        }
        else{
          val element = bucket.last
          bucket.remove(bucket.last)
          bucket.add((element._1 + v ,element._2 ++ Map(k->v) ))
        }
      }
    }
    bucket.toSet
  }
```

Comment: Your description/requirements are a bit vague. You say you "want to distribute the elements as evenly as possible", but your "perfect" solution produces a difference of 19190 between the maximum distribution (20000) and the minimum distribution (810). If you were to distribute them into only 2 different collections then the difference between the max (20000) and everything else (11810) is only 8190. Wouldn't that be a more even distribution?

Comment: Thank you very much for your question, if you say in two pieces is more reasonable, this is a variable, can be modified at any time, I just give an example of a more perfect solution in 4 pieces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

1. Sort map elements from the highest to the lowest (by the value of map entries).
2. Create a sorted set of buckets containing two values: the sum of values and the list of entries and is sorted from highest to lowest.
3. Take the last bucket and add element from the list to it while updating sum.
4. Continue until all elements are processed.

Implementation:

```
import scala.collection.immutable._
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def distribute(elements: Map[String, Int], bucketCount: Int) = {

  //we use sorted set to make sure bucket with least sum is at the end
  implicit val ordering: Ordering[(Int, Map[String, Int])] = Ordering.by(-_._1)

  @tailrec
  def go(
      elements: List[(String, Int)],
      acc: SortedSet[(Int, Map[String, Int])]
  ): List[Map[String, Int]] = {
    elements match {
      case (x @ (_, value)) :: xs =>
        go(
          xs,
          //We take a bucket with the least sum of values and append a new element to it
          //with the sum updated, then we append new bucket to list and truncate it to 
          //desired elements count. 
          acc.last match {
            case (sum, bucket) => (acc + ((sum + value, bucket + x))).take(bucketCount)
          }
        )
      case Nil =>
        acc.toList.map(_._2) //at the end, we just need to drop sums and take only maps
    }
  }

  go(elements.toList.sortBy(-_._2), SortedSet((0 -> Map.empty[String, Int])))
}

distribute(
  Map(
    "table1" -> 100,
    "table2" -> 500,
    "table3" -> 20000,
    "table4" -> 10,
    "table5" -> 1000,
    "table6" -> 200,
    "table7" -> 10000,
    "table8" -> 1000
  ),
  4
).foreach(println)
```

It will print:

> Map(table3 -> 20000)
>
> Map(table7 -> 10000)
>
> Map(table5 -> 1000)
>
> Map(table2 -> 500, table6 -> 200, table1 -> 100, table4 -> 10)

[Link to scastie.](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/clzhngvPTKqkd2cUcgXvXA)

Comment: I tested different numbers of pieces and looked perfect, thank you very much.

Comment: I went to a formal test and found that there were duplicates of the averagely distributed elements, and there were bugs in the code.

Comment: Maybe try to isolate testcases that can reproduce that unexpected behavior and add it to question.

Comment: I've added the data, and you can do a test

Comment: Seems to be working [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/3KMPXb7nRAeEsYajTzjJ3w). Can you try to reproduce it on there?

Comment: The result was not true, with a total of 227 keys, and only 104 keys after the calculation, 123 fewer than the data set.